# Is there a way to define a function through symbolic derivation?

Tags: python, function, diff, sympy

Is there a way to define a function through symbolic derivation? For example,

```
def f(x):return x**x
def df(x) : return diff(f(x),x)
```

This code doesn't work, since `df(1)` would not be possible (`diff(f(1),1)` doesn't make sense.) But is there a way to take advantage of the result of "diff"? When printing `df(x)`, there is a pretty function form with variable `x`, so neat.

Comment: Everything is possible. So the question should rather be: is there already a built-in mechanism for that? No. Is there a library that does that? Unlikely, since this would require some very hardcore hacking of Python's internal structures (i.e. function objects). Python functions are not mathematical functions after all. If you really need that then I suggest using some specialized mathematical language (e.g. maple).

Comment: Where is your definition of `diff`?

Comment: diff is a python command which does symbolic differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need Maple or Mathematica. Python has sympy.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, diff, lambdify

x = symbols('x')

def f(x):
    return x**x

def df(x):
    return diff(f(x))

print(df(x))
```

This returns the symbolic derivative, `x**x*(log(x) + 1)`. Now, it depends on what you want to do with that. It seems like you wanted to calculate numeric values without necessarily knowing that the derivative is `x**x*(log(x) + 1)`. sympy's recommended way for calculating many numeric values is to use its `lambdify`.

```
df_numeric = lambdify(x, df(x), modules=['numpy'])
df_numeric(5)
```

This gives 8154.4934763565643. You can check it against a regular, manual function:

```
def df_manual(n):
    return n**n*(np.log(n) + 1)

df_manual(5)
```

Comment: You could also do `print(df(x).subs(x,5))`. This first derives with respect to x and then replaces x with 1 in the result.

Comment: @Hannebambel Yep! I just mentioned `lambdify` because I assumed the asker would use the function for many values. But `subs` is okay for one-off results, as the docs mention here when comparing the two (A useful link for anyone reading): http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html

Comment: Both the answer and the comment hear answer my question! Thanks

Comment: Worked perfectly in plotting both the original function and its derivative.

Comment: What is the role of "modules=['numpy']" inside lambdify? lambdify(x, df(x), modules=['numpy'])

Comment: @J.S Good question. When sympy goes from symbolic to numeric evaluation, it needs to have vectorized functions from numpy, scipy, etc., to know what to do. So if `lambdify` results in a symbolic `log`, then it uses numpy's `log` for the numeric version. Very basic ones are in numpy. It's not always straightforward, though. For fairly common ones like factorial and the gamma function, I've had to refer `modules` to scipy.